# BTRFS file system

Tags: btrfs

I am new to *btrfs* world. How to find underlying device of BTRFS? Like is it a disk or LVM or a partition? I have tried commands like `btrfs scan device`. But it just gives the general statistics of the device but not actully a type of device. Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Probably related: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ

Comment: Does `btrfs filesystem show` command give you the info you seek?

Answer (score 0):

You can whatch your BTRFS by the follow open source tool an play around:

- gparted

Possible, that will advance you current imagination about the BTRFS structure.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to get what you want to know:

- `# sudo btrfs filesystem show --all-devices --human-readable`
- `man btrfs-filesystem`

Exemple:

```
# btrfs filesystem show --all-devices --human-readable
Label: 'rootfs'  uuid: 44d484b7-a780-43a2-a1e4-fc98bac776e6
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 11.38GiB
        devid    1 size 46.56GiB used 11.00GiB path /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt
        devid    5 size 47.71GiB used 11.03GiB path /dev/mapper/sdc3_crypt
        devid    6 size 46.59GiB used 10.00GiB path /dev/mapper/sdb3_crypt
        devid    7 size 45.62GiB used 10.03GiB path /dev/mapper/sdd3_crypt

Label: 'boot'  uuid: a886a9f7-f2ae-4c0e-8293-6b3b3d5b9fa2
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 435.97MiB
        devid    5 size 715.16MiB used 714.12MiB path /dev/sdc2
        devid    6 size 238.32MiB used 237.31MiB path /dev/sdb2
        devid    7 size 238.00MiB used 237.00MiB path /dev/sda2
        devid    8 size 951.67MiB used 740.44MiB path /dev/sdd2

Label: 'home'  uuid: 803e2f56-8c2f-4d34-83a0-d999b0f2c37a
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 5.30TiB
        devid    1 size 884.71GiB used 884.71GiB path /dev/mapper/sda4_crypt
        devid    5 size 2.68TiB used 2.68TiB path /dev/mapper/sdc4_crypt
        devid    6 size 3.59TiB used 3.59TiB path /dev/mapper/sdb4_crypt
        devid    7 size 3.59TiB used 3.59TiB path /dev/mapper/sdd4_crypt
```